# Java - How shorten if statements using lambda expressions?

Tags: java, lambda

First of all, I'm aware that there is a similar questions like this. The answer to that question, however, did not help me.

I have the following code:

```
boolean result = fields[x][y + 1].getRing().getPlayer() == player || fields[x][y - 1].getRing().getPlayer() == player || fields[x + 1][y].getRing().getPlayer() == player || fields[x - 1][y].getRing().getPlayer() == player
```

The code is supposed to check if there are any rings of the current player above, under or next to the current field.

I'm trying to make this code more readable by using a lambda expression, but I can't get it right. I'm not sure whether this is even possible, though.

I tried to replace `fields[x][y]` by a variable `field` and then have `field` become `fields[x][y+1], fields[x][y-1], fields[x+1][y], fields[x-1][y]`

```
boolean result = field.getRing().getPlayer() == player -> field = {fields[x][y+1], fields[x][y-1], fields[x+1][y], fields[x-1][y]};
```

But this gives me a syntax error, which I expected, since `field = {fields[x][y+1], fields[x][y-1], fields[x+1][y], fields[x-1][y]};` sets field to an array, and does not iterate over that array.

Is there any way I can make this code shorter using lambda expression?

Comment: "The answer to that question, however, did not help me." Please give a link to the question you found and explain in detail why it doesn't help you.

Comment: I suggest that you start by writing a normal method instead of a lambda. This will help you think through what you want to do and help you avoid the syntax errors you are getting. Once you have a named method which solves the problem, you can more easily translate it into a lambda.

Comment: I don't think lambdas can be used to shorten this.  You might want to just make some methods to make the code more readable.  C.f. [Extract Method](https://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You keep repeating the same condition, on 4 different values. So what you want in fact is to avoid this repetition, and write the condition once. And you want to test if any of the 4 values match the condition. So start by storing the 4 values in a collection:

```
List<Field> neighbors = Arrays.asList(fields[x + 1][y],
                                      fields[x - 1][y],
                                      fields[x][y + 1],
                                      fields[x][y - 1]);
```

Then test if any of those values match the condition:

```
boolean result = neighbors.stream().anyMatch(field -> field.getRing().getPlayer() == player);
```

This doesn't necessarily make the code faster or shorter, but it makes it more readable, and DRY.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think lambdas will help here.  What I think is better is just to introduce some methods so that the code is more readable.

For example, you could make four methods `ringAbove`, `ringBelow`, `ringRight` and `ringLeft` and that would make the code a little more readable.

```
boolean result = ringAbove(x,y) || ringBelow(x,y) || ringRight(x,y) || ringLeft(x,y);
```

Now just implement each method, with a bit of refactoring:

```
private boolean ringAbove( int x, int y ) {
    return ringAt( x+1, y);
```

}

The other three methods can be implemented similarly.

I don't really understand this code, but lets just assume it works.  `player` will need to be available as a global variable, or you'll need to also pass it as a parameter.

```
private boolean ringAt( int x, int y ) {
     if( x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= fields.length || y >= fields[x].length )
          return false;
     return fields[x][y].getRing().getPlayer() == player;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another "tiny embedded domain specific language" for
dealing with positions and fields. It makes use of Java8 Streams and lambdas.

The method `neighborhood`
abstracts the idea of the shape of a discrete geometric neighborhood, so
that is becomes very easy to deal with all kind of neighborhoods on the 
grid, for example with something like this:

```
 #     ###      # #
#x#    #x#     #   #
 #     ###       x
               #   #
                # #
```

You wanted the first case, but in the code below, it would be very easy to 
replace the concept of "neighborhood" by the 8-cell neighborhood (second case), or by something even weirder, like for example the allowed moves of a knight in chess (third case).

The method `neighboringFields` makes use of the stream of the purely geometric positions, performs some additional checks on it (to ensure that you don't leave the game universe), and then enumerates all the fields with their content.

You can then use these streams of fields to quickly check various predicates on them, for example using the `allMatch` and `anyMatch` methods, as is shown in the very last method `checkRingsInNeighborhood`,
so that the unwieldy if-expression collapses to just this:

```
return neighboringFields(pos).anyMatch(
    field -> field.getRing().getPlayer() == player
);
```

Here is the full code snippet:

```
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

class NeighborPositions {

    // Mock up implementations of `Ring`, `Player`, and `Position`, 
    // whatever those things are
    public static class Ring {
        private Player player;
        public Ring(Player player) {
            this.player = player;
        }
        public Player getPlayer() {
            return this.player;
        }
    }

    public static class Player {
        private final String name;
        public Player(String name) {
          this.name = name;
        }
    }

    public static class Field {
        private final Ring ring;
        public Field(Ring ring) {
            this.ring = ring;
        }
        public Ring getRing() {
            return this.ring;
        }
    }

    // you probably want to fill it somehow...
    public static int DIM_X = 100;
    public static int DIM_Y = 42;
    public static Field[][] fields = null; 

    /** Position on a rectangular grid */
    public static class Position {
        final int x;
        final int y;
        public Position(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }

    /** Shortcut for accessing fields at a given position */
    public static Field field(Position p) {
        return fields[p.x][p.y];
    }

    /** Generates stream of neighboring positions */
    public static Stream<Position> neighborhood(Position pos) {
        return Stream.of(
            new Position(pos.x + 1, pos.y),
            new Position(pos.x - 1, pos.y),
            new Position(pos.x, pos.y + 1),
            new Position(pos.x, pos.y - 1)
        );
    }

    /** Generates stream of neighboring fields */
    public static Stream<Field> neighboringFields(Position pos) {
        return neighborhood(pos).
            filter(p -> p.x >= 0 && p.x < DIM_X && p.y >= 0 && p.y < DIM_Y).
            map(p -> field(p));
    }

    /** This is the piece of code that you've tried to implement */
    public static boolean checkRingsInNeighborhood(Position pos, Player player) {
        return neighboringFields(pos).anyMatch(
            field -> field.getRing().getPlayer() == player
        );
    }
}
```

You obviously shouldn't try to cram everything into a single file and declare it `public static`, it's just an example.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Player>` that, given `x` and `y` coordinates, returns a `Player`:

```
BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Player> fun = (coordX, coordY) ->
    fields[coordX][coordY].getRing().getPlayer();
```

Now, to check whether a given `player`'s ring is above, under or next to a given pair of coordinates, you could use:

```
boolean result = List.of(
        fun.apply(x, y - 1), 
        fun.apply(x, y + 1), 
        fun.apply(x - 1, y), 
        fun.apply(x + 1, y))
    .contains(player);
```

This uses Java 9's [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E-E-E-E-). If you are not in Java 9 yet, just use `Arrays.asList`.

Besides, it also uses the [`List.contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) method, which checks if a given object belongs to the list by means of the `Objects.equals` method, which in turn uses the `equals` method (taking care of `null`s). If `Player` doesn't override `equals`, then identity equality `==` will be used as a fallback.